# Execute a powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a powershell script that I want to start when Windows 7 starts 
how can I do that?

Comment: Have to start before user login?

Comment: No, it can starts after a user login

Answer (score 2):

If you run this command at startup, you should be fine:

```
powershell.exe -noexit c:\scripts\MyAwesomeScript.ps1
```

More info on this subject can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx

Comment: I need to have a file that contain the code and auto-execute after login...like a .bat I presume...

Comment: You could put this in a .bat and make it run that way, but I'm pretty sure you can drop this command in a Group Policy Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Start -> Run -> taskschd.msc. Create a basic task and set the trigger to "When the computer starts". Select "%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" for your program name and set the full path to your powershell script as it's argument. Note that this will only run when a user logs in to the machine.

If instead you need this script to run without requiring a user to login, then goto Start -> Run -> Gpedit.msc. Under computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts, double click on the "Start Up" icon to edit it's properties. Click on add and then the "Script Name" to be "%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" and your script parameters to be the path to your powershell script. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add a link to your powershell script into StartUp folder.

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp